# How to convert an X509Name Object to a string in Python

Tags: python, linux, ssl, openssl

I am trying to capture the subject field as a string using the hostname. Like this:

```
/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=*.google.com
```

The same output can be obtained using

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null | grep subject
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=*.google.com
```

Tried some subprocess module to get the above output but ended up falling on OpenSSL module to help me out because I am not well versed in Subprocess module. Using OpenSSL, I was able to get the desired output but it is returning it as an X509Name Object:

```
import socket, ssl
import OpenSSL

hostname = "google.com"

cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((hostname, 443))
x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
print(x509.get_subject())

<X509Name object '/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=*.google.com'>
```

I want it to return this as a string. Can this be achievable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [[pyOpenSSL]: crypto - X509Name objects](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#x509name-objects) (*get_components*) for more details.

It  is possible, with a bit of processing. The distinguished name string is the concatenation of the individual component strings, where each component string is in the form of `/name=value`.

**Example**:

> ```py
> >>> import ssl
> >>> import OpenSSL
> >>>
> >>> pem = ssl.get_server_certificate(("google.com", 443))
> >>> cert_x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
> >>>
> >>> subject = cert_x509.get_subject()
> >>> subject
> <X509Name object '/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=*.google.com'>
> >>>
> >>> subject_str = "".join("/{:s}={:s}".format(name.decode(), value.decode()) for name, value in subject.get_components())
> >>> subject_str
> '/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=*.google.com'
> ```

There are multiple ways of getting certificate data, here's another one: [[SO]: How can I decode a SSL certificate using python? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899247/how-can-i-decode-a-ssl-certificate-using-python/50072461#50072461).

Comment: Yours is the better solution as you use the module. I'm replacing my own `re.sub` with your solution. For reference `re.sub(r'^<X509Name object \'(?P<subject>.+)\'>$', '\g<subject>', x509.get_subject().__str__())`